# Fill a list given a starting value at a specific index

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of starting values which all should go into index 152 of a new list which goes from the starting value (at the 152nd index) to some maximum, and then starting from zero again up to the starting value with some regular spacing.

To make this more clear with a simpler example, imagine my starting list looks like this: [3,4,1,2] and these starting values are to be assigned to the second index of a new list of length 8 evenly spaced from a minimum value of 1 to a maximum value of 4. I need to generate four lists that look like the following:

[2.5,**3**,3.5,4,0.5,1,1.5,2] with 3 as the starting value in the second index

[3.5,**4**,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3] with 4 as the starting value in the second index

[0.5,**1**,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4] with 1 as the starting value in the second index

[1.5,**2**,2.5,3,3.5,4,0.5,1] with 2 as the starting value in the second index

My actual starting list is 20 entries long so I need to generate 20 new lists with each of those starting values in the 152nd index of a 192 index long list. The minimum value is 0 with a maximum of 24. So going from the starting value, the rest of the list should be filled with even increments to go from start value to max value and then from min value back to start value-increment keeping the starting value in the 152nd index.

I hope this makes sense. It is hard to explain, and probably why I am having trouble coding it as well. I have an idea for how to do it, however I am curious if there is an obvious pythonic way I just haven't learned yet. Thanks!

Edit:

Here is what I have:

```
nlon = 192
lon_idx = 152
lt = [19.6, 19.65, 19.7]

spacing = 24/nlon
nbefore = lon_idx - 1
nafter = nlon - lon_idx
time_dict = {}
for i in lt:
    b = nbefore
    a = nafter
    temp = [i]
    while b > 0:
        val = temp[0]-spacing
        if val < 0:
            temp.insert(0, 24)
        else:
            temp.insert(0, val)
        b -= 1
    while a > 0:
        val = temp[-1]+spacing
        if val > 24:
            temp.append(0)
        else:
            temp.append(val)
        a -= 1
    time_dict['lst_%s' % i] = temp

print (time_dict['lst_19.65'][151])
```

It works, but its not pretty. I also need to keep these new lists in order as they pertain to data in another numpy array.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: `"I have an idea for how to do it"` Just do it!

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted...its an interesting problem. I could provide the scraps of code I have, but as stated in the question I am having a hard time figuring this out (and the code isn't complete)...hence why I am here on stack overflow asking for help.

Comment: I added some code that does what I want...but its not pretty. I actually plan to convert these to numpy arrays. I am going to use these arrays to mask another array based on values in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that builds your new arrays as rows in a 2D Numpy array. It uses the simplified data you've shown, but it should also work with your larger data set, if I've understood your description correctly. ;)

The key idea is to build an array `base` with the desired steps between entries. We then rotate `base` so that when we combine it with the starting values they will appear in the correct column. We use modular arithmetic to ensure that all the values of the new arrays are within the desired range.

```
import numpy as np

# The starting values in a column array
lt = np.array([3, 4, 1, 2])[:, None]

# The number of entries in the new arrays
num_entries = 8

# The offset in the new arrays of the starting values
offset = 1

# The highest value permitted in the new arrays
hi = 4

# Step size between the values in the new arrays
delta = hi / num_entries

# Create an array of the steps
base = np.linspace(0, hi, num=num_entries, endpoint=False)
# And rotate it so the starting values are at the correct offset
base = np.roll(base, offset)

# Build the new arrays
new_arrays = (base + lt - delta) % hi + delta
print(new_arrays)
```

**output**

```
[[ 2.5  3.   3.5  4.   0.5  1.   1.5  2. ]
 [ 3.5  4.   0.5  1.   1.5  2.   2.5  3. ]
 [ 0.5  1.   1.5  2.   2.5  3.   3.5  4. ]
 [ 1.5  2.   2.5  3.   3.5  4.   0.5  1. ]]
```

Comment: Wow, see that is what I was looking for. So much simpler than what I was doing. I am trying to teach myself to think like this but it's tough to do so when you don't know the tools that are available. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Will.Evo Not a problem. Numpy is fun. And fast! Although I've been using Python for a decade I'm still relatively new to Numpy, so there may be even more efficient ways to do what my code does, but I can guarantee that my code will be a lot faster than equivalent code using plain Python loops.